# Group Styling of ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

My CollectionViewSource looks likes this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding PlayerNodeDTO}"/>
```

My lIstview which is binded to the above CVS looks like this:

```
<ListView Margin="0,30,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}" Height="578" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent"   x:Name="liveGrid" SelectionChanged="PlayerNodeSelected">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,10,0,0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                <Border Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
                                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.GroupStyle>

                                <GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,60,0"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid Height="28">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Margin="23,0,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle>
                            </ListView.GroupStyle>
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <controls:Control1/>
                                        <controls:Control1/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

Now when I havent added any groupdescription, everything works fine,i.e, my list view displays 4 items in one column(as determined by size of controls) and as soon as one more item comes, it displays in the second column like this:

4 4 4
4 4 4
4 4
4 4

But when i add a group desciption, all the items in a particular group are displayed vertically as :

Group1    Group2
4         4
4         4
4         4
4         4
4         4
4         4

I want all the items within each group to also follow the exact same behavior as described earlier.

Comment: The second set of 4's are in the group2

Comment: What are the 4's good for????